# Best way to find in an array if there is X + Y = S

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

What is the best way to check in an array if there is 2 numbers X,Y in an array called A which X + Y = S.
S can be any number(Not necessarily exists in A).

I said, let's **sort** the array which costs O(nlogn) for the worst case **then let's take 2 pointers for the first element and another pointer to the last element.**

Start **comparing** if pointer 1 + pointer 2. if result bigger then **decrease** pointer 2 by 1. if result smaller then **increase** pointer 1 by 1. until we move on all the eles in A.

**Time complexity:** nlogn + n(Worst case for moving in 2 pointers) = nlogn.

is there any better solution ?

Comment: With a help of `HashMap` (`Dictionary`) you can have `O(n)` time complexity (as well as `O(n)` space usage for the `HashMap`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a hash-based set and add all elements from A to it. Then you can iterate through A elements and check if S - A_i exists in this set. Assuming that contains and put operations on hash-based set work in O(1), you'll solve your problem in O(n).

Comment: If your input range is constrained, you don't even need a full hash set - just a big bit mask with bits set if they're in the input.  If you don't have negative numbers in the input, nothing will be larger than `S`.

Comment: @MarkRansom can the bit mask change the time complexity? And, I don't see sufficient evidence in this answer supporting O(n)

Comment: @danh no a bit mask doesn't change the complexity, just reduces the overhead. You don't have to compute hashes for example.  And as long as every operation is O(1) as stated in the answer, the overall complexity will be O(n) because each element is examined only once.